# No highlight for watched tags anymore?

Tags: support, tags, design

I see the design of the WPSE homepage has changed—different display for question metadata on the side (eg # of answers, question score, etc).

It also appears that the soft yellow highlighting of questions with one or more of my "Watched Tags" has disappeared. In the past, if someone tagged a question with, eg, [multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite), it would be visually flagged in the homepage list. That seems to be gone.

Is it coming back? If not, what's the reason for removing it? (Did I just miss a blog post on the topic? I very well could have.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I'm seeing `Ignored` and `Watched` items in the left-hand nav. Maybe I missed them before; maybe they took some time to roll out to me. Works for me, in any event. Thanks!